# Static website on GCP over HTTPS not working

Tags: https, google-cloud-platform

I have a .dev domain that requires the website to be hosted using HTTPS.

I am hosting a static website on GCP. For the HTTPS Certificate, I've created one using Letsencrypt and also tried using GCP generated Cert.

I am using a Load-Balancer setup to use the HTTPS cert and serve the static website out of Storage bucket.

However when I go to my site I am told it is not secure. I am currently using GCP generated Cert, waited 12 hours and I get the following error.

[image]

How can I fix this so that I don't see it, nor need to add an exception. In this case I am even unable to add an exception with a .dev domain.

Also I have a follow up question. How can I force all HTTP traffic to use HTTPS using the Load-Balancer?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by doing the following:

1. Change Load-balancer IP from ephemeral to static.
2. Add A record of Load-balancer IP to DNS record.

Side note: if you got a Static website working with HTTP, you will also need to change the CNAME entry pointing to **c.storage.googleapis.com.** to an A record with the IP record of the Load-balancer.